# Definite article The usage

Tags: articles, definite-article

Why definite article “the” is used before 1)Historical monuments (example: The TajMahal).  2)Books and newspapers (example: The Harrypotter and The Indian Express)  and   3)Plannets (The earth) ,Although they are proper nouns?

Comment: The Earth is the _only_ planet that takes a definite article, to avoid confusion with other senses of the word _earth_. I don't know what you mean by 'The Harrypotter' - _Harry Potter_ is a personal name and does not take an article.

Comment: Because English is not consistent (like most languages, but each in its own way). Monuments tend not to take "the" (_Stonehenge_, _Angkor Wat_, _Salisbury Cathedral_, _Tien-an-men Square_) unless their names are descriptions (_The Great Wall of China_, _The Giant's Causeway_, _The North Pole_) but as you say, _The Taj Mahal_ doesn't fit that pattern, and nor does _The Alhambra_. If you look at bridges of New York in Wikipedia, you'll see that though the article titles don't use "the", the articles themselves do; whereas those of bridges in London mostly don't.

Answer (score 0):

When the object or group of objects is unique or considered to be unique. In accordance to A Practical English Grammar by Audrey Jean Thomson & A. V. Martinet, published by Oxford University Press. You may find a pdf file online. It's helpful.

Answer (score -1):

'The' isn't usually used before singular proper nouns. But there are some exceptions. 
'The' is used :

> 1. Before historical monuments, museums,etc. :

The Tajmahal, the British Museum.

> 2. Before religious books :

the Quran, the Ramayana, the Bible.

> 3. Before the name of books with the author's name :

The Sonar Tari of Rabindranath Tagore. 
The Harry Potter of J. K. Rowling. 
The Macbeth of Shakespeare.

> 4. Before the names of newspaper :

The Indian Express, The Statesman, The Telegraph.

> 5. Before those which are unique (i.e., "only one" in this universe) :

the earth, the moon, the sky, the stars.

There are much more exceptions which you can learn from any good grammar books. Thank you.